# Upgrade all modules installed by local::lib

Tags: perl, locallib

I've been using local::lib to handle the installation of Perl modules on a server so I can get the right versions for some development work without polluting the system installation.

However, the system administrator has recently upgraded Perl from 5.16 to 5.18 and I'm now getting errors relating to binary modules, e.g.

```
perl -e 'use Scalar::Util'
Perl API version v5.16.0 of List::Util does not match v5.18.0 at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.18.2/XSLoader.pm line 92.
Compilation failed in require at /home/paul/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/Scalar/Util.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

My understanding is that I can fix the problem by forcing local::lib to rebuild all of its modules, but I can't find anything in the documentation which tells me how to do this, or even how to get a list of all the modules that have been installed using local::lib (if I had that in a 'one module per line' text file, I could easily write a Bash script to process it).

Is this possible, or do I have to remove the ~/perl5 directory and reinstall all the modules from scratch (possibly missing some as I can't remember them all)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Update***: For some time now, `INSTALL_BASE` has been producing a better directory structure that avoids this problem for new installs.

And that's why the `perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=...` convention (and the corresponding one for `Build.PL`) used by install::lib sucks.

Removing (or renaming the directory so you have backup) is the easiest solution. You can find out what you had installed by looking for `.pm` files.

```
cd ~
mv perl5{,16}
cd perl516/lib/perl5
find -name '*.pm' | xargs perl -MConfig -E'
   for (@ARGV) {
      s!^\./!!;
      s!^5\.\d+\.\d+/!!;
      s!^x86_64-linux/!!;
      s!^auto/!!;
      s!\.pm\z!!;
      s!/!::!g;
      say;
   }
' | xargs cpan
```

(Do a dry run — one without the trailing `| xargs cpan` — first.)

Note that if you don't want to be at the mercy of your admin's upgrades, you can use `perlbrew` to easily install a whole build of Perl in your home dir.

Comment: Thanks - I used your answer to generate a list of modules and then ran those through `perl -MCPAN -Mlocal::lib -e "CPAN::install($module)"` (as per the `local::lib` docs). I've put some wrapper code around it to reinstall `local::lib` and handle errors gracefully and it seems to work fine, though it does take a long time and tries to install a lot of modules which don't exist.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `cpanm` you can force it to rebuild modules in your `local::lib` location by using the `-L` and `--reinstall` switches:

`list_modules | cpanm -L ~/perl5 --reinstall`

where `list_modules` is a script that feeds the names of modules to `cpanm` (there's also an `-f` option to `cpanm`). This script could be like @ikegami's above or something like [`cpan-outdated`](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpan-outdated) (which only lists outdated modules however). Here is a
hackish attempt that mostly worked for me recently (note: ikegami's is probably better) - when it fails or the script gives `cpanm` a module name it doesn't recognize, `cpanm` keeps going and doesn't seem to break anything (but make backups):

```
cd $PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT  
perl -MFile::Find -MConfig -E'
      find { 
        wanted => sub { 
                       $mod = $_ if /\.pm\z/; 
                       $mod =~ s/lib\/perl5\/auto\/.*//g;
                       $mod =~ s/lib\/perl5\/\Q$Config{archname}\E\/.*//g;
                       $mod =~ s/lib\/perl5\///g;
                       push @mods, $mod unless $mod =~ /^$/;
                      },no_chdir=>1 
           },"lib/perl5"; @modhash{@mods}=(); say for sort keys %modhash '
```

By changing where and what `File::Find` finds with `wanted()` you can feed a different list of modules to `cpanm`. It would be nice if `cpan` or `cpanm` had an internal `_method` or `-switch` that allowed you to force the rebuilding of `local::lib` installed modules that use XS.  Is there such a thing?

It was `cpanm`, `carton` (and seeing the `node.js` tool `npm` in action) that inspired me to do a lot more `local::lib` based installs. Now the CORE bundled "CPAN client" that ships with perl (`cpan`) seems to be getting more automagical and easier to use as well. I really like `local::lib` since it allows you to use the system `perl` but manage your own module stack without system level privileges. However, it can be easier overall to manage changes and upgrades if you use `perlbrew` to run a "non system" ("local") `perl`. Of course you can do this **and** still have `local::lib`, `carton` *etc*. manage a directory or application specific stack of modules.

1). Another way to do an upgrade is to use `perllocal` to generate a list of your currently installed modules (**NB** I'm not entirely sure if `perllocal.pod` is kept in a reliable/useful state). **[Edit:** In fact `perllocal` keeps a *history* of your installed modules rather than a list of those *currently* installed. You'll want to filter this or you will end up reinstalling the entire series of module versions one after the other!). This perlmonks node shows how to clean up your `perllocal.pod`: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=483020. I prefer to keep the history.**]**

To parse `perllocal.pod` for input to `cpanm`, search through the file saving the matches in an array, then split them by twos to create a hash from the array elements (`key,value,key,value`). More recent installations and versions numbers are lower in the file, so you can create a hash with module names as keys and have the values updated by later entries:

```
 perl -ne 'push @arr, grep {defined}
 (/\A=head2.*:\s+C<Module>\s+L<(.*)\||.*C<VERSION:\s(.*)>\Z/msx); }{
 %h = map{ split/,/,$_,2 } @arr; print "$_\@$h{$_}\n" for keys %h' perllocal.pod
```

(NB: this doesn't error check - entries in `perllocal.pod` occasionally lack `VERSION` data and other oddities so beware.)

2). *But* this method pales in comparison to the shell script mentioned by ilmari in #perl-help on IRC. It uses
[`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) - a commandline utility you *really need to have* (you'll want it more after this).  If you have used [`cpanm`](http://cpanmin.us) to install your modules it will have created `install.json` files. You can leverage that to make list to feed  to `cpanm` for reinstalling your current set of modules:

```
 find ~/perl5/ -name install.json -exec jq '.name + "@" + .version' {} +
```

Very fast, very simple and you can combine it with the `cpanm` method of using `curl` to self-install in order to rebuild your modules.

3). If you use `perlbrew` to manage your perl installations you can [easily copy and reinstall](http://perlbrew.pl/Reinstall-All-Modules-On-New-Perl.html) all your modules from one `perl` version to another.

HTH!

Comment: I made the same change to mine, but I reverted it. We want the `archname` of the originally installed Perl (`x86_64-linux`), not the currently installed one (which could be different). I'll leave it up to you what you want your code to be.

Comment: uh oh does this mean I have to remember the difference between `/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/mach/` and `$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5/amd64-freebsd-thread-multi` ...  :-)  Anyway I see the chicken/egg issue regarding upgrades that might occur. I quite like your simple backup/re-install approach with `mv perl5{,16}` and `find`

Comment: you'll need `-r` for `jq` to stop it from quoting values