# Moving / cloning a perlbrew installed perl plus all the additional cpan modules

Tags: perl, cpan, perlbrew

I am using perlbrew. I have installed lots of cpan modules under `perlbrew perl-5.20.2`.

Is there a way (or what is the best way) to do a tarball installation of my perl-5.20.2 plus all the CPAN modules that I have installed under perlbrew so that I can just clone it unto another machine?

I am aware of `perlbrew download perl-5.20.2` but that only seems to tarball perl-5.20.2 and not all the CPAN modules that I have installed.

Comment: You could take the approach described in [How To Reinstall All Modules On New Perl](http://perlbrew.pl/Reinstall-All-Modules-On-New-Perl.html), but write the output of `perlbrew list-modules` to a file, copy the file to the other machine, and use it as the input for `perlbrew exec`. However, this would require downloading the entire set of modules twice, and you would get the latest version of everything, so you might have version mismatches between your two installations.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot ++ With `cpanm`  you can use versions - as in `cpanm Plack@0.9990`, but there's no option to get a current version list with `'perlbrew list-modules`. One way to get a pretty good list of current versions of modules installed under - say - `~/perl5/` is to look for any `install.json` files and process those. *e.g.* `find ~/perl5/ -name install.json -exec jq -M '.name + "@" + .version' {} +`. This assumes `install.json` exists. Tweaking the output format that so `perlbrew exec cpanm` likes it would probably be needed

Answer (score 5):

With perlbrew you can use the `lib` command to create a `local::lib` to go with your perlbrew perl.

```
perlbrew lib create perl-5.20.2@app_reqs
```

Then, if all goes well, when you install modules you will find them in:

```
$HOME/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.20.2@app_reqs
```

If you don't use the `perbrew lib create` approach to managing your modules, then they are installed to `$HOME/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.2`.  Cloning either of those directories might work, but you are likely better off reinstalling all the modules using the techniques from the [perlbrew.pl website](http://perlbrew.pl/Reinstall-All-Modules-On-New-Perl.html) since XS modules should be rebuilt *etc*.

If you want to reuse and track local sources the most reliable approach is to create a local CPAN mirror to work from using [`App::lcpan`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/App::lcpan) or [`minicpan`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/minicpan). If you have already downloaded the source using `cpanm` a quick hackish approach is to find the source files (under `$HOME/.cpanm/`) and do something like this in your shell:

```
% mkdir  ~/cpansourcefiles  
% for source in ~/.cpanm/work/*/* ; do cp $source ~/cpansourcefiles ;done
```

Then you can get `cpanm` to install using those sources by passing the filename as the argument instead of the module name:

```
% cpanm ~/cpansourcefiles/List-MoreUtils-0.406.tar.gz
```

or even:

```
% cpanm ~/cpansourcefiles/*
```

**NB:** YMMV since this is prone to breakage and might skip some of the version and dependency checking you normally get with `cpanm` but it is simpler than setting up a mirror when it works.

---

A few other high powered tools that make deploying Perl applications  robust and reliable:

- [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton)
- [Pinto](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pinto)

---

**EDIT**:

Tools like `perlbrew`, `pinto`, `carton`, and `cpanm` are a vast improvement over a motley personal collection of scripts for doing similar things. Thanks to all the developers and contributors to these tools!

I'm not aware of any features in `cpanm` or `perlbrew` that allow you to reliably produce a list of installed files ***and*** their versions. Something like:

```
 cpanm --list_installed
 perlbrew list_installed_versions
```

or:

```
 cpanm --export-cpanfile
 perlbrew list_installed_as_cpanfile
```

might be a welcome feature.

As I noted in a comment to the OP above, you can garner useful information about your module installation from the `install.json` files that are installed by `cpanm`. Modules like [`CPAN::Meta`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Meta), [`Module::Metadata`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Metadata) and [`Distribution::Metadata`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Distribution::Metadata) can be helpful too.

The suggestion to use `find` and `jq` (which was from @Ilmari Karonen see [Upgrade all modules installed by local::lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620814/upgrade-all-modules-installed-by-locallib/25630911#25630911) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25630911/2019415)) led to the quick unfinished hack below. One challenge/issue is there's sometimes `install.json` files left lying around in multiple locations:

- `lib/perl5/$Config{archname}/.meta/Whatever-Mod-1.0050000/install.json`
- `lib/perl5/$Config{archname}/.meta/Whatever-Mod-1.0090000/install.json`
- ... *etc.*

This is likely because these files are not always cleanly removed when upgrading, reinstalling or other mucking about PEBKAC errors. To work properly, the code below should be changed so that it notices when there are multiple name-version combinations of a module's `install.json` and then does a more thorough check that the module is installed and gets its version. The script should have options: `$dir` could come from `@ARGV`. TIMTOWTDI, "well volunteered", *etc*.

```
#!perl  
# list_installed_mods.pl 
# DOES NOT THOROUGHLY VERIFY CURRENT VERSION

use File::Find;                                       
use JSON;                                       
use v5.16;     
my $dir = "$ENV{HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5";      

for my $installed ( find_installed($dir) ) {     
  say parse_install_json( $installed );     
} 

sub find_installed {  
  my $libdir = shift;    
  my @files;   
  File::Find::find ({ wanted => 
    sub { push @files, $File::Find::name if /install\.json/i} },
    $libdir );
  return @files; 
} 

sub parse_install_json {
  my $filename = shift;
  my $json_text = do {   
   open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)                
      or die("Can't open \$filename\": $!\n");                          
   local $/;
   <$json_fh>                                                           
  }; 
  my $install = decode_json($json_text) ;   
  return ( $install->{name} ,"\@", $install->{version} ) ;
}
```

Comment: see also: [`cpanm-meta-checker`](https://metacpan.org/release/App-cpanm-meta-checker) ...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the best way, but here's what I did recently.

I committed my Perlbrewed Perl version to a git repo, so I could use `git archive` to create a tar for me. Likewise with my `Local::Lib` modules.  Then I wrote a little bit of scripting so that I could tag master, build archives from a tag, copy the archive to the remote server, unpack and chmod/chown the files.

I did this because at the time it was a quick and dirty solution to not having the time to set up Pinto or Carton.

Comment: ++ I can't see how this wouldn't work when you have perl only modules (no XS) and a simple installation. My approach (see my answer) - which was to copy source files from `~/cpanm` and install them directly to avoid downloading - felt similarly hackish but worked for a `local::lib` perlbrew installation that had only a few dozen modules installed.  I used `perlbrew` to build perl itself (the same version of course) from source.

Comment: I used perlbrew to insall everything I needed, locallized under a perlbrew directory, including XS and pure perl modules. perlbrew keeps each version of perl compartmentalized, so I could just tar up a git tag starting at a version's root directory.  A few lines of script to set the correct perlbrew env vars on the target server, and it all worked.  Woudl I have liked a solution using the evolving standards? Yes. But is wasn't in the cards for that project.

Answer (score 1):

It's only part of the solution but want mentioned so far: Perl's configure script has a -D relocateableinc parameter since some versions.
When building/brewing a Perl with that option the lib paths won't be hardcoded absolute path but relative to the perl binary which allows you to move the entire directory around or just rename it.
I'm building all my Perl's with that option since years and it hasn't created any problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

The [clone-modules](https://perlbrew.pl/Reinstall-All-Modules-On-New-Perl.html) command might be what you're seeking.

Example output for the below command follows:

`perlbrew clone-modules perl-5.36.0 perl-5.37.6`

```
Installing 398 modules from perl-5.36.0 to perl-5.37.6 ...

! Couldn't find module or a distribution AWS-Signature4
Successfully installed Algorithm-Diff-1.201
Successfully installed Algorithm-Loops-1.032
Successfully installed Module-Build-0.4231
Successfully installed ExtUtils-PkgConfig-1.16
Successfully installed Alien-VideoLAN-LibVLC-0.04
Successfully installed File-Slurp-9999.32
```

You can run this command after building a new `perl` with `perlbrew` to *migrate* (the latest versions of) CPAN modules from one version to another by **reinstalling** them for the new version that was just built.